# How to use changeLanguage method in next-i18next for changing locale?

Tags: next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I'm trying to change default locale in my project with just button click. I don't want to change my URL with pushing sub paths like `fooo.com/fa`.

Here is my [next-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next) config:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'fa'],
  },
};
```

And here is my simple code for changing locale and using that:

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('common');
   ///
<button onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage('fa')}>
    Click to Change Language
</button>
<p>{t('title')}</p>
```

But it does not work and stuck in default locale that is EN.

Comment: "I don't want to change my URL with pushing sub paths" - any reason why not? That's how Next.js i18n sub-path routing is meant to work.

Comment: This will cause our CDN to crash (because the URL has changed and is no longer cached)... so we don't have other way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - shouldn't the CDN be caching the routes for all possible locales of the app?

Answer (score 6):

*This worked for me:*

```
const changeLocale = (locale) => {
        router.push({
            route: router.pathname,
            query: router.query
        }, router.asPath, { locale });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It sounds crazy, but yeah: official documentation doesn't contain how to change language. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar and came up with this:

`pages/some-route`

```
export async function getAllTranslationsServerSide(locale: string) {
  return serverSideTranslations(
    locale,
    ["common"],
    nextI18nextConfig,
    nextI18nextConfig.i18n.locales
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await getAllTranslationsServerSide(locale)),
    },
  };
}
```

`components/SomeComponent.tsx`

```
function changeLanguage(locale) {
  i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
  router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, {
    locale,
    scroll: false,
    shallow: true,
  });
}
```

I wanted to change locale (including the sub-path as my project uses [NextJS sub-path routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing)) but without re-triggering other API requests that a route might need and hence any potential re-renders (I was getting some ugly white flashes).

The key bit is loading all locales in `getStaticProps`.

This means that when `changeLanguage` is called the required translation strings are already loaded client-side.

This works for my small app but is probably a bad idea for apps with more translations.